# How can i redirect all url from a webpage

Tags: php

I have an old webpage. Peoples find it from Google. How can i redirect all search to another domain with PHP?
Example:
From `www.domain.com/oldnews.html`
to `www.newdomain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header will redirect.

```
header('location: http://www.newdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: www.newdomain.com");
```

But, if you have shell access you are probably better off using rewrite rules rather than editing every single page individually.  Read up on mod-rewrite.